# How to run test in xt at once?

Tags: perl, testing

Is it possible to run the tests in a `xt` directory all at once from the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `prove` tool has many options you can tweak. A useful invocation could be `prove -l -r xt`, which includes the `lib/` folder in `@INC`, recurses into subdirectories, and starts in the `xt` folder. This would run all test in a directory structure like

```
lib/
  Foo.pm
xt/
  000-start.t
  001-sometests/
    001-foo.t
    002-bar.t
```